# Node.js & Eclipse integration

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I have installed updates of nodeclipse,but i am not able to  run my java script file even though when i run them in node folder. 
i get these errors like:
1)provisioning exception
2)No repository found

Answer (score 0):

Correct name is `nodeclipse`

As said in http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support you should

> I got this error and I'm sure it's a bug -- raise an issue!
>
> Should you report a bug, please include the following:

1. Nodeclipse version number (like 0.4 or 0.8)
2. Eclipse version number (like 4.3.1 Kepler or 4.4.0)
3. Eclipse distribution (e.g. Eclipse for JEE Developers)
4. A detailed description of the steps necessary to reproduce the problem.
5. Screenshot and stack trace, that you can get from Eclipse Error Log View (Window -> Show View ...) or from '.log' file from the directory '.metadata' in your workspace.
6. See example issue #78